# Filling specific missing value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have two columns which are `PREVAILING_WAGE` and `JOB_TITLE` in my dataset.

`JOB_TITLE`:

```
ANALYST, BRAND DEVELOPMENT
ANESTHESIOLOGIST
ANESTHESIOLOGIST
BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE ANALYSTS
CIVIL ENGINEER
CIVIL ENGINEER
COMPUTER PROGRAMMER
COMPUTER PROGRAMMER ANALYST
COMPUTER SYSTEM ANALYST
COMPUTER SYSTEM ANALYST
COMPUTER SYSTEMS ANAGLYST
COMPUTER SYSTEMS ANALYST
CONSULTANT
CORPORATE COMMUNICATIONS SPECIALIST
COUNSELOR
DESIGN
ELEMENTARY CO-TEACHER
FASHION MODEL
FIELD ENGINEER
FINANCIAL ANALYST
FINANCIAL SENIOR ANALYST
FINANCIAL SPECIALIST
```

These values correspond to the `NAN` values in the PREVAILING_WAGE column. Normally my data size is (700.000 X 2)

```
df2 = df[df.PREVAILING_WAGE.isnull()]
df3 = df2.sort_values(by='JOB_TITLE',ascending=True)
print(df3.JOB_TITLE)
```

I want to fill out these `JOB_TITLE`'s Wage (`PREVAILING_WAGE`) column.

I want to find the average salary value of each job_title and then assign it to the empty ones.

**For example**, Computer Programming average salary 90k, and Computer Programming which doesn't have salary information can be implemented 90k

I saw a similar question on the following link but it does not contain the info I want

[Filling Missing values Pandas Dataframe by specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052270/filling-missing-values-pandas-dataframe-by-specific-value)

Comment: what did you try ? And what result did you get ? Did you find average salary of each job_title ? I would use `group_by` for this. After that you can start thinking how to replace values. Maybe you could do it even in groups created with group_by.

Comment: Hi Furas, above listed job titles have missing salary parts. I want to fill these. Taking the mean values of other data (for each job_title)

Comment: so first calculate mean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I create some random data with `NaN` - so I can test code.

```
job_title = '''ANALYST, BRAND DEVELOPMENT
ANESTHESIOLOGIST
ANESTHESIOLOGIST
BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE ANALYSTS
CIVIL ENGINEER
CIVIL ENGINEER
COMPUTER PROGRAMMER
COMPUTER PROGRAMMER ANALYST
COMPUTER SYSTEM ANALYST
COMPUTER SYSTEM ANALYST
COMPUTER SYSTEMS ANAGLYST
COMPUTER SYSTEMS ANALYST
CONSULTANT
CORPORATE COMMUNICATIONS SPECIALIST
COUNSELOR
DESIGN
ELEMENTARY CO-TEACHER
FASHION MODEL
FIELD ENGINEER
FINANCIAL ANALYST
FINANCIAL SENIOR ANALYST
FINANCIAL SPECIALIST'''.split('\n')

job_title = list(set(job_title))

# --- create random data with some NaN
import random

data = []

# rows with `NaN`
for _ in range(1):
    for item in job_title:
        data.append( (item, None))

# rows with random SALARY
for _ in range(2):    
    for item in job_title:
        data.append( (item, random.randint(10000,100000)))    

# put all in random order
random.shuffle(data)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['JOB_TITLE', 'SALARY'])
```

So now I have `DataFrame` with random data and `Nan` so I can create solution

This line gives me filter to see only rows which have `NaN` - I will use it to see rows before and after work.

```
rows_with_na = df['SALARY'].isna()
```

I can see these rows before work

```
print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df[ rows_with_na ])
```

I tried `groupby` `JOB_TITLE`, get `mean()` and update `NaN` with `fillna()` in group but this doesn't change original `df`

```
print('\n--- mean ---\n')

groups = df.groupby(['JOB_TITLE'])

for idx, grp in groups:
    mean = grp['SALARY'].mean()
    print('mean:', mean, idx)
    print(grp['SALARY'].fillna(mean)) # doesn't work as I expected
    print('---')
```

But using groups and `transform` with `fillna` and `mean` I can get changes in `df`

```
groups = df.groupby(['JOB_TITLE'])

#df['SALARY'] = groups.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
#df['SALARY'] = groups.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))['SALARY']
df['SALARY'] = groups['SALARY'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Now I can see these rows after work

```
print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df[ rows_with_na ])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My question is exactly that.